# Want to change the color of lable

Tags: flutter, android-studio, colors, label, flutter-bottomnavigation

I tried to change the color of label but I can't how can I change the color of label I used?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider to generate your own widget item and use it in **"icon"**

The label option **only accepts a String**

The title option **is not recommended**

[image]